# Rails devise space error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, space, var

I've no change anything from my rails app, and today when I was trying to get there, I've got the following error:

```
Errno::ENOSPC in Devise/sessions#new

Showing /var/www/services/compolib/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

No space left on device - /var/www/services/compolib/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets%2Fcffd775d018f68ce5dba1ee0d951a99420121230-22757-1fwwx98
Extracted source (around line #6):

3:   <head>
4:     <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
6:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:     <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.2.min.js", 'application' %>
8:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
9:     <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
Rails.root: /var/www/services/compolib

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1997016315920621486_42305140'
```

I've gone to see what's wrong with the file system, and it's like this:

```
deployer@one4:~/compolib/tmp$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             3850292    421916   3428376  11% /
none                    496384       140    496244   1% /dev
none                    509664         0    509664   0% /dev/shm
none                    509664      6868    502796   2% /tmp
none                    509664        76    509588   1% /var/run
none                    509664         0    509664   0% /var/lock
none                    509664         0    509664   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr   4184064   2805952   1378112  68% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-var   4184064   4184044        20 100% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home
                       4184064   2472208   1711856  60% /home
```

So it seems to be that /var is out of space. But why? Is devise gem filling all /var space?
How to fix it? Because /tmp folder from my app is empty.